# Flex site won't load blank white screen

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I've created a Flex site that runs in the browser and it works on my machine but it won't show on anyone else's computer. I searched online and found nothing but I think it has to do with me monkey patching the FlexSprite class.

What do I need to do to get it to work on another person's computer?

**MORE INFO**
My project is setup like this:

*/MyFlexProject (runs fine in the browser on my machine)*

Build Path Libraries:
*/MyProjectLibrary

/MyProjectLibraryAssets

/MyGenericPersonalUtilitiesLibrary

/ExternalLibrary*

Source Path Libraries:
*/${DOCUMENTS}/MyProjectFlexSDKPatches/src*

**UPDATE**
On the main project I've set the framework linkage to "merge into code" and still it doesn't load on other computers. In Chrome it shows a blank screen. On Firefox it loads partially and is stuck on the progress bar. The same thing happens on my other computer.  After reloading a few times in Firefox it finally worked?? I'm attaching a screenshot so you can see where it gets stuck at.

[image: loading not complete]

Even though it finally worked it is not acceptable because I need it to work every time the first time. Could it be that the other libraries are trying to load from a remote server?

Comment: Since you're attempting monkey patching; I assume you are not using RSLs, but set it the Framework to "Merge into Code"?

Comment: On the main project or all projects? I've set the main project to "merge into code" and it doesn't load on my brothers computer. On my other computer it hangs part way and after reloading a few times it finally worked??

Comment: I meant on the main project.  I didn't think the "merge into code" was avaialble on library projects.  Are their multiple SWF projects associated with this?

Answer (score 0):

if you havent released it, you should try adding the folder of the swf to the Flash Player trusted location on the viewers machine. It is done in debugger mode automatically. Go to control panel -> flash player.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I can't go to everyones machine to have them enable it.

Comment: 1) try making a release version. 2) try tracing with MonsterDebugger in Firefox, to see, where it gets stuck. 3) Try what I said the first time, if it solves it, at least you know the problem, and can start working on it.